# Does the Instagram Business API through Facebook's Graph API support the like/comment/relationship endpoints?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Can we POST likes/comments and manage relationships of an Instagram account through the business Instagram API that utilzies the Graph api? Thanks!

Comment: only comments are supported